# assign more users to folder on powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

everyone please help me, I need a command to assign permissions to a folder in the directory tree, conditional on the correct directory name to be assigned. I am trying to write a command line but when assigning a group or a user, it can be assigned but other users are removed, I want to not remove any users.

```
$mypath = "D:\KIEM TRA1" 
$myacl = Get-Acl $mypath 
$myaclentry = "EMC0\test.ktnb","readandexecute,write","Allow" 
$myaccessrule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($myaclentry) 
$myacl.SetAccessRule($myaccessrule) 
Get-ChildItem -Path "$mypath" -Recurse -Force | 
Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'A' -or $_.Name -eq 'B' } | 
Set-Acl -AclObject $myacl -Verbose
```

I want to do it on a subdirectory and not remove the existing user

Comment: Please show us the code you have already tried. Also explain whether you want subfolders to also follow this rule (inherit from the parent folder) or not

Comment: $mypath = "D:\KIEM TRA1"
$myacl = Get-Acl $mypath
$myaclentry = "EMC0\test.ktnb","readandexecute,write","Allow"
$myaccessrule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($myaclentry)
$myacl.SetAccessRule($myaccessrule)
Get-ChildItem -Path "$mypath" -Recurse  -Force | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'A' -or $_.Name -eq 'B' } | Set-Acl -AclObject $myacl -Verbose ;
I want to do it on a subdirectory and not remove the existing user

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is to create a new access rule using 5 parameters, so you can handle inheritance and propagation too.

Try this (always on a set of test folders first of course..)

```
$mypath = "D:\KIEM TRA1" 
$account = "EMC0\test.ktnb"

# see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights
#      https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.inheritanceflags
#      https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.propagationflags
$rule = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new($account, "Modify", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow") 
# on older PowerShell versions use:
# $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($account, "Modify", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")

# get a list of folder FullNames of subfolders with name 'A' or 'B'
$folders = (Get-ChildItem -Path $mypath -Directory -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^[AB]$' }).FullName
foreach ($directory in $folders) {
    # get the current ACL of the folder
    $acl = Get-Acl -Path $directory
    # add the new rule to the ACL
    $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
    $acl | Set-Acl -Path $directory -Verbose
}
```

Note:

Instead of `AddAccessRule()`, you might prefer `SetAccessRule()`.

**AddAccessRule**
This method will add this access rule to the ACL.
If a user has Modify permission and we use AddAccessRule() to create a new rule with Read permission the user will *still also have* Modify permissions.

**SetAccessRule**
This method removes any existing access an *replaces that access* with the specified rule.
If a user has Modify permission and a new rule is created using SetAccessRule() specifying Read permission, that user will now only have Read permission.

Comment: thanks! thank you ! but it shows this error


Method invocation failed because [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule] does not contain a method named 'new'.
At line:7 char:1
+ $rule = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new($account, "Rea ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: @khuchatvui What version of Powershell are you using? Try with New-Object syntax as I have edited in as comment